# GPX to Profile like Giro d'Italia?

Tags: software

my dream is to have a tool that generates profiles like Giro D'Italia:

[image: profile example]

in which:

- we can add text of locations;
- we can add the maximum profile signal

Comment: what's the question? You can pick up a beginner-friendly language like Python and roll out your own profile generator.

Comment: This question should get migrated to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does https://veloviewer.com/ do it for you?

[image: https://cf.veloviewer.com/img/veloviewer-route-3d-homepage.png]

Looks like it ties into strava.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend VeloViewer (in general as well as for this). There is also the option for a 2D version more similar to the one in the question available under the 3D profile tab.

Comment: I'm a VV user also, so many features! It's what Strava *should* be ...

Comment: VV can also examine individual Strava segments, rather than just the entire ride. For instance, the Zoncolan analysis: https://veloviewer.com/segments/1635485

Comment: Thank you, I've explored the VV and it's very good in making charts. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A height profile for a past ride can be obtained from Strava:

[image: strava screenshot]

If you need a almost exact picture, with incline highlights, and selected topographic names pointed out, I think the only way to achieve that is to write a program yourself, combining data from free sources: Openstreetmap for names and open DEM data for elevation information. Elevation information can be extracted from a GPX file written by most devices, but its accuracy will be less.

Comment: You could do it without programming for a one-off, with some photoshop skills and manual labelling

Comment: Good point about GPX elevation